# Timer of swing not performing as expected

Tags: java, swing, timer, repaint

I was suggested not to use `sleep` for pausing purpose and instead use `swing` `timer` but still its not working.The animation i want to achieve is a ball travelling from the top left corner diagonally towards the bottom.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Show_starter {

    int x, y;
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Graphic_show");
    Graphic_panel jp = new Graphic_panel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Show_starter start = new Show_starter();
        start.go();
    }

    private void go() {
        window.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, jp);
        window.setSize(600,800);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class Graphic_panel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);

                x++;
                y++;

                try {

                    Timer tmr = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener()); //This fires an event after every 1 sec after it has started by start().
                   //But The ball travels too much fast and stops at a point and again travels very fast.
                    tmr.serRepeats(false); // even this is not working.
                    tmr.start();
                    //should i use repaint here or in Listener for this timer?
                } catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }

        class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jp.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The behaviour it is showing is very odd ball first goes at very high speed and stops momentarily at a point and again moves at same speed.

I have also tried to change the time for `timer` event to fire but the same thing happens.

Even inside loop where I have started `timer` the follow function call is not working

```
setRepeats(false);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide more details on the behaviour that is actually occurring. Thanks.

Comment: why do you use a loop inside paint component?

Comment: @FastSnail whats wrong with that?

Comment: @Rouftantical yes ...that's why it's so fast .

Comment: @FastSnail i mean what is happening inside the loop, the reason for its speed?

Comment: @Rouftantical timer interval is one second in a animation big time .and your x and value get incremented to very large value .and also like luxxMiner pointed out you are creating lot of new timers

Comment: @FastSnail what should i do?

Comment: @Rouftantical i answered ckeck it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't create new timers always one timer is enough .decrees timing  interval bit more .1 second is too slow for a animation.you don't need a loop and don't increment x and y inside `paintcomponet()` method because this method get called for some reason for example when you resize,minimize,maximize.

the unexpected behavior is due to your loop and creating new timers(). for example in x y start at zero but in first second x y increased to 100,100 in next paint you see them in a 100,100 position .that's look like quick move and then stop ...

example code (edited)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Show_starter {

    private Timer tmr;

    int x, y;
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Graphic_show");
    Graphic_panel jp = new Graphic_panel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Show_starter start = new Show_starter();
        start.go();

    }

    private void go() {

        window.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, jp);
        window.setSize(600, 800);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tmr = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() { // time gap in millisecond

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                jp.increse();
                jp.repaint();
            }
        });
        tmr.start();

    }

    class Graphic_panel extends JPanel {

        public void increse() {
            x++;
            y++;
            if (x > 100) { // stop animation at x>100
                tmr.stop();
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);

        }

    }
}
```

output (smoother than that)

[image]

Comment: @Fast Snail , I think it is better to use `runnable` or `Thread` here

Comment: @FastSnail I think he wants to do some sort of animation as he mentioned. Then it is needed to `repaint()` it many times , `timer` isn't for animation right

Comment: @Rahul i'm not sure but then for what timer ? i think as he mentioned he still use  his sleep animation code so he hasn't correctly modify to work with timer

Comment: @FastSnail can you tell me why should i not use loop inside paintComponent

Comment: @Rouftantical you can use but if you use you will see quick movement because it increse x y location to 100 suddenly .but you shoudn't do it inside paintComponent method. try to resize your form then see what happens to your previous animation .because you are not the only one call paint method .so you can't see smooth animation

Comment: @Rouftantical and i recommanded you to run my code example .. important thing is ball's x y should increase  with a interval .inside a loop it just increased .so it's not a animation

Comment: @FastSnail , `Timer` is like scheduling the job. For example saving a file in a interval of time. On the otherhand `runnables` give better control for this animations

Comment: @FastSnail when it will stop??

Comment: @Rouftantical you should call `stop()` method on timer .when do you want to stop?

Comment: then timer need to be declared as a instance variable because inner class wants to access it?

Comment: Btw i am not upgrading x direct to 100 i am doing it linearly.why are you saying this?

Comment: @Rouftantical consider this code `for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){ x++; y++;g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);}`   this code run linearly but you can't see it .it's so quick.that's why we put a time gap in a animation's frame outer wise we can only see start position and end position .you only see ball at 0,0 position and  then 100,100 . so you don't see a leaner motion .instead you see quick .
`The behaviour it is showing is very odd ball first goes at very high speed and stops` high speed mean it position at 100,100 cuz loop doesn't take at least a millisecond to complete 100 iterations .

Comment: @Rouftantical this code  `for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){ x++; y++;}` exactly same as `x+=100;y+=100;` your loop is not doing what you think it should do .but when you use `thread sleep` it works because you sleep inside the loop .then there is a time gap between frames .think why did you use a sleep method when you use thread to animate .actually you should understand thread and timer is not equal .if you don't get it tell me

Comment: @Rouftantical i edited the answer , now it animation will stop when  x coordinate exceed 100

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should not use a `loop` inside `paint component`.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
}
```

Just draw it and make `x` and `y` public in the class so that you can easily access from outside

Now run a `runnable` (consult `invokelater` and `swingUtilities`) or create a new `Thread`

inside `public void run()` do whatever animations you want to do . You can use a loop but add `Thread.sleep(//in miliseconds)` and `repaint()` in each iteration .

**note :**  you need to change the `x` and `y` and `repaint()` so that it is drawn in a new position. And the `sleep()` is needed to slow down the execution otherwise it can't be visible to viewer.

Comment: why should i not use loop inside paintComponent?

Comment: because it will load the `component` much slower. The animation will be done once it is loaded. And every `repaint` will do another animation for you (not only you `repaint` it , it can be repainted by other events too) . There will be animations when you don't even ask for it and slow the system.  I don't think you really need this.